# Visual Studio Code remote-ssh creating too many zombie processes

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using VS Code's remote-ssh to connect to a Linux server.

The output of `top` is shown below, with the zombie process's command as “node”:

[image: output of top]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem. In my experience it stems from workspace searches (ctrl + shift + f) and file searches (ctrl + p). Ever since I started ending searches by clicking the 'clear search results button':

[image: clear search results button]

, results have been better. As a backup, using 'kill -12 'pid'' (pid as seen in top process table above) to close node processes regularly is the only way to not choke the system.

If I come across a better way to stop VSCode from spawning these processes, I will update this answer.